# Actions on Google Streaming Audio Now?

Tags: actions-on-google, audio-streaming, google-home

I'm trying to build a Google Home Action for a radio station. According to Google, it isn't supported on Google home. "Audio for playback must be in a correctly formatted .mp3 file. Live streaming is not supported." https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/rich-responses

However, if you look at the Google home actions "marketplace" I see quite a few actions for radio stations and streaming audio. Like this one: https://assistant.google.com/services/a/uid/000000f203c7b79a?e=-WebDirectoryEmbeddedWebviewExperiment&jsmode=o&hl=en-US&source=web

Is it possible to stream audio in a Google Home action now?

Answer (score 0):

Streaming media actions are not created by individuals but are provided through partner services in areas such as [radio stations](https://developers.google.com/actions/media/reference/data-specification/radiostations-specification).

Generally, it is still not possible to build an Action to stream live audio.

Comment: What if I'm building this for a radio station?

Comment: ["Currently, Google is working with a limited number of providers at a time to integrate each provider into the feature. You're welcome to read the documentation until we can open it up to more providers."](https://developers.google.com/actions/media)

Comment: There are a ton of different developers that are doing live streaming. And some of them don't appear to be big companies either. Does anyone know how to become one of the providers that Google is working with?https://assistant.google.com/explore/i?intent=PlayRadio&category=10&hl=en-US

Comment: I believe this is now possible: "Live streaming is only supported for the MP3 format." https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/prompts-media

Answer (score 0):

I already tried. It is really possible to use conversational actions and media responses (see the link Dev Ze posted already - https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/prompts-media). Instead of providing a static file, a mp3 stream (icecast) can be used.

But there might be some problems with duration shown on the device. Some icecast servers return a content-length which then google will use to calculate a stream duration - but this does not make any sense on icecast streams.

Also the meta information sent through iceast isn't parsed by google. So track information will never be updated during streaming. Even there is no event where the developer could update the track info via code.